# Google Static Maps WPF recover mouse coordinates on image

Tags: wpf, google-maps, coordinates

Good Morning everyone,
I have a little question for you, i am currently on a project with google maps and static maps. I am working on WPF and i managed to get the position of the mouse X,Y on the image. While the mouse is moving on the image,  i would like to receive the coordinates, lat, long.

Is that possible ?

Thanks alot for your help and future answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See:

```
http://home.provide.net/~bratliff/largetiles/
```

The mouse events may not work in some browsers.  The Mercator projection functions are the same in every browser.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, i will post it as soon as i am back from work !

And EDIT this post.

Comment: There is a Google MAP API with mouse click which returns the coordinates ^_^ I'm sorry It's been a while and I thought I had done this.

Comment: It's all good :D, was only teasing. Found a map component for WPF with the source code and an example so implemented the mouse move logic needed. For those interested, find it here: http://greatmaps.codeplex.com/